# How do I put editor templates in an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editortemplates

I know how to put plain text and code in the editor. Is it possible to put an editor template programmatically in an Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442138/eclipse-accessing-a-editor-template-from-plugin-code

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for an editor for plugin development then you can go for *new* -> *plug-in project* and then opt plugin with editor which creates a sample class and entry in `plugin.xml` which can be a start for you.